# The Speed Loss When i use mutex in Thread Synchronization

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

i use mutex exclusion to notify the four sub-thread to decode code stream,but i find it's cost more time compared with just use single thread.(These four threads each decode a quarter of this code stream, but a single thread decodes the entire code stream.)

first i define eight mutex(Four are used to notify the start of decoding, and the other four are used to notify the end of decoding)

```
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex1));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex2));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex3));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex4));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag1));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag2));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag3));
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag4));
```

second,Take the mutex first when releasing the thread.when i want to decode my code-stream,i release my mutes,like follow code:

```
    (do some prepare)
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex1));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex2));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex3));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex4));
```

sub-thread Process code is following,(example thread 1)

```
 pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->mutex1));
 (decode)
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag1)); // this send signal for decode over
```

i wait mutex ensure all thread has been decoded,like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag1));
pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag2));
pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag3));
pthread_mutex_lock(&(mymultidecoder->overflag4));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Stop right now and read the [tour] and [ask].  This is vital for asking appropriate, on-topic questions here.  Guessing how to use this site will almost always lead to your question getting closed and deleted.

Comment: If you are using C++ use std::thread, std::mutex and std::scoped_lock. Rewrite your code show a minimal reproducible example of your problem (including errors) and then ask the question again.

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to make all four of those worker threads start as close as possible to the same time. Why? What bad thing could happen if more time elapsed between the start of the first worker and the start of the last one?

Comment: FYI: You cannot unlock a mutex from within a different thread than the one that locked it. Use a [`binary_semaphore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/counting_semaphore) for that. Mutex and binary_semaphore are very similar, but "mutex" tells other programmers who read your code\* that you are trying to keep threads from interfering with each other when they use shared variables, while "semaphore" tells other programmers that you are trying to send a signal from one thread to another. \[\*E.G., other programmers whom you have asked for help to understand some problem.]

Answer (score 6):

> i use mutex exclusion to notify the four sub-thread to decode code stream,but i find it's cost more time compared with just use single thread.

Yes, it can be the case that a parallel version of some procedure performs worse than a corresponding serial version.  Overhead from activities such as manipulating mutexes is among the common causes.

One of the keys to effective parallelization is therefore to ensure that the amount of work done concurrently by multiple threads is large compared to the amount that is done serially.  In your case, the actual decoding work is concurrent, but all the prep work and all the mutex setup and manipulation is serial (notwithstanding that the latter is performed in multiple threads).

But in your particular case, ...

> first i define eight mutex(Four are used to notify the start of decoding, and the other four are used to notify the end of decoding)

... sounds pretty horrendous.  *Eight* mutexes?  Absurd.  And mutexes are not well suited for signaling.  I might in general recommend instead *one* mutex plus *one* condition variable, used properly.  Or perhaps some semaphores.  Unlike mutexes, semaphores can be unlocked (incremented) by a thread different from the one that locked them (decremented them to 0).

But in your particular case, I don't see why you need any mutexes at all.  Your threads will not perform any work before you start them, so do all the prep first.  And you can know when each one is finished by `pthread_join()`ing it, which you should be doing anyway.  If there are no data races then that's all you need.  And if there are data races, then they are not addressed any more by what you describe in the question than by the approach described here.

Even so, this might not help much.  If you're not already seeing at least some advantage from multiple threads (and you have enough cores available that they can in fact all run concurrently) then you probably don't have enough total work for parallelization to be worthwhile.